# High error messages in the WP database at the moment "1596 [Warning] Unsafe statement written..."

Tags: mysql, wordpress

At the moment, I see a lot of errors in the database that I don't know why.
I use the latest version of WordPress, Plugins and PHP.
Sample error codes:

```html
2020-04-04 15:21:44 1596 [Warning] Unsafe statement written to the binary log using statement format since BINLOG_FORMAT = STATEMENT. INSERT... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE  on a table with more than one UNIQUE KEY is unsafe Statement: INSERT INTO `uvc_options` (`option_name`, `option_value`, `autoload`) VALUES ('_transient_wps_excluded_hostname_to_ip_cache', 'a:0:{}', 'no') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `option_name` = VALUES(`option_name`), `option_value` = VALUES(`option_value`), `autoload` = VALUES(`autoload`)
2020-04-04 15:21:44 1596 [Warning] Unsafe statement written to the binary log using statement format since BINLOG_FORMAT = STATEMENT. INSERT... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE  on a table with more than one UNIQUE KEY is unsafe Statement: INSERT INTO uvc_statistics_visit (last_visit, last_counter, visit) VALUES ( '2020-04-04 15:21:44', '2020-04-04', 1) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE visit = visit + 1
2020-04-04 15:21:51 1596 [Warning] Unsafe statement written to the binary log using statement format since BINLOG_FORMAT = STATEMENT. INSERT... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE  on a table with more than one UNIQUE KEY is unsafe Statement: INSERT INTO `wp_options` (`option_name`, `option_value`, `autoload`) VALUES ('_site_transient_timeout_rocket_partial_preload_process_lock', '1585997571', 'no') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `option_name` = VALUES(`option_name`), `option_value` = VALUES(`option_value`), `autoload` = VALUES(`autoload`)
2020-04-04 15:21:51 1596 [Warning] Unsafe statement written to the binary log using statement format since BINLOG_FORMAT = STATEMENT. INSERT... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE  on a table with more than one UNIQUE KEY is unsafe Statement: INSERT INTO `wp_options` (`option_name`, `option_value`, `autoload`) VALUES ('_site_transient_rocket_partial_preload_process_lock', '0.72089200 1585997511', 'no') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `option_name` = VALUES(`option_name`), `option_value` = VALUES(`option_value`), `autoload` = VALUES(`autoload`)
2020-04-04 15:21:57 1596 [Warning] Unsafe statement written to the binary log using statement format since BINLOG_FORMAT = STATEMENT. INSERT... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE  on a table with more than one UNIQUE KEY is unsafe Statement: INSERT INTO `wp_options` (`option_name`, `option_value`, `autoload`) VALUES ('_transient_timeout_external_ip_address_5.115.15.90', '1586602317', 'no') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `option_name` = VALUES(`option_name`), `option_value` = VALUES(`option_value`), `autoload` = VALUES(`autoload`)
2020-04-04 15:21:57 1596 [Warning] Unsafe statement written to the binary log using statement format since BINLOG_FORMAT = STATEMENT. INSERT... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE  on a table with more than one UNIQUE KEY is unsafe Statement: INSERT INTO `wp_options` (`option_name`, `option_value`, `autoload`) VALUES ('_transient_external_ip_address_5.115.15.90', '185.94.97.238', 'no') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `option_name` = VALUES(`option_name`), `option_value` = VALUES(`option_value`), `autoload` = VALUES(`autoload`)
2020-04-04 15:21:57 1596 [Warning] Unsafe statement written to the binary log using statement format since BINLOG_FORMAT = STATEMENT. INSERT... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE  on a table with more than one UNIQUE KEY is unsafe Statement: INSERT INTO `wp_options` (`option_name`, `option_value`, `autoload`) VALUES ('_transient_timeout_wc_related_11939', '1586083917', 'no') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `option_name` = VALUES(`option_name`), `option_value` = VALUES(`option_value`), `autoload` = VALUES(`autoload`)
2020-04-04 15:21:57 1596 [Warning] Unsafe statement written to the binary log using statement format since BINLOG_FORMAT = STATEMENT. INSERT... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE  on a table with more than one UNIQUE KEY is unsafe Statement: INSERT INTO `wp_options` (`option_name`, `option_value`, `autoload`) VALUES ('_transient_wc_related_11939', 'a:1:{s:53:\"limit=4&exclude_ids%5B0%5D=0&exclude_ids%5B1%5D=11939\";a:0:{}}', 'no') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `option_name` = VALUES(`option_name`), `option_value` = VALUES(`option_value`), `autoload` = VALUES(`autoload`)
```

If anyone has a suggestion to fix the problem, please let me know